# Is it possible to query by array content?

Tags: fiware-orion

Using the FIWARE PointOfInterest data model I would like to filter by POI category which is an array. For instance

```
http://130.206.118.244:1027/v2/entities?type=PointOfInterest&options=keyValues&attrs=name,category&limit=100&q=category=="311"
```

having as entity instances something like

```
{
        "id": "Museum-f85a8c66d617c23d33847f8110341a29",
        "type": "PointOfInterest",
        "name": "The Giant Squid Centre",
        "category":
        [
            "311"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "Museum-611f228f42c7fbfa4bd58bad94455055",
        "type": "PointOfInterest",
        "name": "Museo Extremeño e Iberoamericano de Arte Contemporáneo",
        "category":
        [
            "311"
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking to [the NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) it seems that works in the way you mention:

> Single element, e.g. `temperature==40`. For an entity to match, it must contain the target property (temperature) and the target property value must be the query value (40) (or include the value, in case the target property value is an array).

I mean, in particular the part that says:

> ...or include the value, in case the target property value is an array.